# InnoSetup : silent install and progress install value in wpf application (for update)

Tags: wpf, inno-setup, updates, silent-installer

In my wpf application, I ask the user to download the update if there is one.
The file is downloaded via my program using this code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(textBox1.Text.Trim()), tempUrl + "Downloaded." + Path.GetExtension(textBox1.Text));
```

I would like to know if it is possible to run the setup installer in silent mode and to get the progress installation on my wpf application. I would like to display a progress bar on my wpf application. I'm using InnoSetup, I know how to start it in silent mode but I don't know how to get the installation progress value.

Comment: If you run the install in `/SILENT` instead of `/VERYSILENT`, then it will display its own progress.  And this is better than doing it in your app, because it means that your app itself could be replaced.  (It's not possible to replace it while it's running.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no public interface for getting progress from Inno Setup in Silent mode or normal mode.

I suppose the only way is to create custom plug-in which reads progress from Inno and sends it to your app.

Or you can modify Inno's sources and add desired functionality into it.

Comment: I've proposed [`this suggestion`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/51) now, since it's often requested feature. I don't know if there's a way to vote for issues on their repository but it might be fine if you'd leave a (positive :-) comment there to pay more attention of it (since I'm not sure the authors are watching StackOverflow).